# using newtonsoft, how to deserialize without knowing the type till run time?

Tags: json, json.net

so the followwing works just fine, giving me a Team object from the string json:

```
var found = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Team>(json);
```

but what if I won't know the type until runtime?  Say I've got the string json as above, but I also have another string with the type name?  for example, this isn't working:

```
var found = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, Type.GetType("Team"));
```

Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type ...

Comment: Could you use the template version? `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)`

Comment: I don't know T until runtime.  I have a string that tells me the type to deserialize into.

Comment: If you have a JArray, it's not going to be an object - you may need to build an IEnumerable Type for your Type.

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me:

```
var type = Type.GetType("My.Namespace.Class");
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(item, type);
```

The trick is to make sure that `type` is not null by providing the correct class name. If it is, the Deserialization can still work, but the output won't be the type you are wanting. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) for more info on `GetType`.